# convert caf on iphone or on server for sharing

Tags: iphone, mp3, caf

I have an app that records short sounds (as caf files) and uploads them to a server.  I want to be able to share these sounds so they need to be in a more ubiquitous format like mp3.  I've got a linux server.  Is there anything I can use either on the iphone or the server to perform the conversion?

thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved my own problem, but I'm open to any other solutions.

I've installed [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) and [libsnd](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) on my server.  If I upload a caf file I can use SoX to convert from caf to mp3.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/sox path_to_caf_file destination_for_mp3_file

Comment: /usr/local/bin/sox /something/something/file.caf something/something/file.mp3